# Include file (svg) in java jsp

Tags: java, liferay

I need to include a raw svg file in a jsp page (liferay portlet) to  manipulate it with css. I usually do this in php with this simple string:

```
<?php include('images/image.svg'); ?>
```

How can I do this in java?

Comment: What did you try so far or what research did you do? Did you have a look at the html tag `<img>`?

Comment: @Thomas i didn't try anything because I don't know Java. I searched for informations but I didn't find how to include files in java (other than classes and other java files). I can't use the `<img>` tag, I need the raw svg source code inside the jsp.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use @include

```
<%@include file="images/image.svg" %>
```